# Is there a way to specify where the Transparent BDSF takes effect on the desired object?

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, transparency

Lets say I have a flat 2D circle (bezier that's been filled). The node setup is simply a transparent BDSF + Diffuse BDSF going into a mix shader.

Is there a way that you can use nodes to make it so only a desired part of the circle appears transparent like in the image?

[image]

I don't necessarily want this exact pattern, I just made some random shape for the example,

Comment: @brockmann Thanks for the feedback. That principle is pretty much what I'm trying to go for, although with bezier curve objects. I tested it just now but I had to convert the curve to a mesh object, and add geometry (filling/cutting with knife tool), in order to get it to work. I guess there's no way to be able to make these kinds of shapes with a bezier filled object right?

Comment: Depends... I'd paint a texture (second answer).

Comment: I'll mess around with it and see if I can make it work, thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's super easy. *Top view > U > Project from view* and then use photoshop as you already do...

Comment: Thanks again dude